# A cubeful of three-dimensional devilry

Tags: cryptic-crosswords, three-dimensional, printers-devilry

> [image]
>
> This is a **three-dimensional cryptic crossword**. The seven squares represent the layers of a $7\times7\times7$ cube. The clues are a mix of Printer's Devilry and normal cryptic clues.
>
> **Across**
> 13. While offense may be overlooked, repeat offenders will be banned (7)
> 14. The guard started to ring the alarm  (7)
> 15. Stuffing into a stereo appliance (7)
> 19. A surprisingly mature beginner (7)
> 20. A spit fed on the runway (7)
> 21. Street next to singer Blunt's orange property (2 5)
> 25. Which of thesis well with fish? (7)
> 26. View screen shot extremely closely (7)
> 27. For the first time, a son's two local teams reached the finals (7)
>
> **Down**
> 10. Tropical island gathering (7)
> 11. Ugly pose – apply support (7)
> 12. Earning disturbed with intent to harm (2 5)
> 16. Middle East native's unstable airtime (7)
> 17. He heard some chapel a table story (7)
> 18. Not taking beginners in silent band (7)
> 22. The company's products in clued candles (7)
> 23. Canine bathhouse attracts horrible line (7)
> 24. Fierce female's time for initial discussion to go off topic (7)
>
> **Away**
> 1.  Painter to suddenly turn around, having ruined major event's introductions (7)
> 2.  Oilstone regularly contains finest variant of element (7)
> 3.  Essential metal extracted from almost offensive hormone (7)
> 4.  No back route, proceeding as planned (2 5)
> 5.  A car holds freight items securely in place (7)
> 6.  Enslaved leftists behind near-broken trap (7)
> 7.  Standard top rating for leading example of Canadian cuisine (7)
> 8.  Embarrassed to stash a medicine sample (7)
> 9.  Laud herself into her seat (7)

Comment: Still having problems visualizing the cube.  If I assume 1 is "ABCDEFG", does the "B" go at the intersection of 10 and 13, and the "D" at 16, 19?

Comment: Are you certain that 17d is correct? (I expect it is, but I'm having difficulty seeing past a not-quite-solution to it and would be glad of confirmation that I really should.)

Comment: @ChrisCudmore Yeah, that's correct. The first letters of the answers go in layer #1.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Hmm maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see anything obviously wrong. That said it's my first time writing this type of clues so it's definitely possible I've made some mistake...

Comment: Ah, no, the error is mine. It's fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Filled grid:

> [image]

Brief explanations:

**Across**

```
13. While offense may be overlooked, repeat offenders will be banned (7)
```

> pd: whi**le a sing**le offense ... (NB while != while)

```
14. The guard started to ring the alarm (7)
```

> pd: ... to r**un, sound**ing ...

```
15. Stuffing into a stereo appliance (7)
```

> cryptic: substring of clue

```
19. A surprisingly mature beginner (7)
```

> cryptic: A + MATURE*

```
20. A spit fed on the runway (7)
```

> pd: a spitf**ire land**ed on the runway

```
21. Street next to singer Blunt's orange property (2 5)
```

> cryptic: ST JAMES (think Monopoly)

```
25. Which of thesis well with fish? (7)
```

> pd: which of the si**des pair**s well ...

```
26. View screen shot extremely closely (7)
```

> cryptic: SCREEN* + (closel)Y

```
27. For the first time, a son's two local teams reached the finals (7)
```

> pd: ... **in ten se**asons ...

**Down**

```
10. Tropical island gathering (7)
```

> cryptic: double def

```
11. Ugly pose – apply support (7)
```

> cryptic: POSE* + USE

```
12. Earning disturbed with intent to harm (2 5)
```

> cryptic: EARNING*

```
16. Middle East native's unstable airtime (7)
```

> cryptic: AIRTIME*

```
17. He heard some chapel a table story (7)
```

> pd: ... some chap**s tell a r**elatable story

```
18. Not taking beginners in silent band (7)
```

> cryptic: NT in QUIET

```
22. The company's products in clued candles (7)
```

> pd: ... inclu**de scent**ed candles

```
23. Canine bathhouse attracts horrible line (7)
```

> cryptic: SPA + LINE*

```
24. Fierce female's time for initial discussion to go off topic (7)
```

> cryptic: DIGRESS with T for D

**Away**

```
1. Painter to suddenly turn around, having ruined major event's introductions (7)
```

> cryptic: VEER contains R(uined)M(ajor)E(event)

```
2. Oilstone regularly contains finest variant of element (7)
```

> cryptic: (o)I(l)S(t)O(n)E contains TOP

```
3. Essential metal extracted from almost offensive hormone (7)
```

> cryptic: (me)T(al) removed from INSULTIN(g)

```
4. No back route, proceeding as planned (2 5)
```

> cryptic: NO< + TRACK

```
5. A car holds freight items securely in place (7)
```

> pd: A car**go sling** holds ...

```
6. Enslaved leftists behind near-broken trap (7)
```

> cryptic: ENS(laved) behind NEAR*

```
7. Standard top rating for leading example of Canadian cuisine (7)
```

> cryptic: POUTINE with R(ating) instead of its leading letter

```
8. Embarrassed to stash a medicine sample (7)
```

> cryptic: substring of clue

```
9. Laud herself into her seat (7)
```

> pd: Lau**rel ease**d herself ...

Comment: Nice job! I think #24 has a typo in the grid (the answer's supposed to be the T word). #14 is not an anagram, although maybe I have misused the indicator in that one. "Stuffing of..." or "...'s stuffing" would maybe have made more sense?

Comment: I think you mean 15, not 14...  rot13(va_gb n fgre_rb)  I'm not sure I like "stuffing" as the indicator.  Stuff or Stuffed would be better.

Comment: Whoops, yes, typo in 24. For some reason I was initially convinced it was going to be the other one, and clearly I still had that in my head when I put the answer in :-). I'm not quite sure how I convinced myself that 15 was an anagram, since the anagram doesn't in fact work. Will fix.

Comment: Could you make the inserted word **bold** in the PD clues?

Comment: That's a good idea. Will do. [EDITED to add:] Now done.

Answer (score 1):

**Here are some clearer explanations for some of the clues:**

**CAUTION**: *This post may contain spoilers or Wikipedia links.*

---

1. (not sure yet)
2. Oilstone regularly contains finest variant of element (7)

   > **ISOTOPE** ([def] variant of element; o**I**l**S**t**O**p**E** contains **TOP** =finest )
3. Essential metal extracted from almost offensive hormone (7)

   > **INSULIN** ([def] [hormone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulin) ; me**T**al removed from **INSULTIN**g)
4. No back route, proceeding as planned (2 5)

   > **ON TRACK** ([def] proceeding as planned; **NO** backwards + **TRACK** for route)
   >  SUGGESTION: Use (2,5) instead of (2 5).
5. A car holds freight items securely in place (7)

   > **GOSLING** ( as in: A car**GO SLING** holds freight items securely in place )
6. (not sure yet)
7. Standard top rating for leading example of Canadian cuisine (7)

   > **ROUTINE** ([def] Standard; **R**ating takes the beginning of [p**OUTINE**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poutine) )
8. Embarrassed to stash a medicine sample (7)

   > **ASHAMED** ([def] Embarrassed; st**ASH A MED**icine)
9. Laud herself into her seat (7)

   > **RELEASE** ( as in:  Lau**REL EASE**d herself into her seat )
10. (not sure yet)
11. (not sure yet)
12. (not sure yet)
13. While offense may be overlooked, repeat offenders will be banned (7)

    > **ASINGLE** (not sure yet, as in:  While **A SINGLE** offense may be overlooked, repeat offenders will be banned )
    >  NOTE: Sorry, our dictionary says that "**ASINGLE**" is not a word.
14. The guard started to ring the alarm (7)

    > **UNSOUND** ( as in: The guard started to r**UN, SOUND**ing the alarm )
15. Stuffing into a stereo appliance (7)

    > **TOASTER** ([def] appliance; in**TO A STER**eo)
16. (not sure yet)
17. He heard some chapel a table story (7)

    > **STELLAR** (not sure yet, as in: He heard some chap **STELLA R**el-a-table story )
18. Not taking beginners in silent band (7)

    > **QUINTET** ([def] band; **N**ot **T**aking in **QUIET** for silent)
19. A surprisingly mature beginner (7)

    > **AMATEUR** ([def] beginner; **A** + **MATURE** scrambled)
20. A spit fed on the runway (7)

    > **IRELAND** ( as in: A spit f**IRE LAND**ed on the runway )
21. Street next to singer Blunt's orange property (2 5)

    > **ST JAMES** ( not sure yet; **ST** for Street)
22. The company's products in clued candles (7)

    > **DESCENT** ( as in: The company's products in-clu**DE SCENT**ed candles )
23. (not sure yet)
24. Fierce female's time for initial discussion to go off topic (7)

    > **TIGRESS** ([def] Fierce female; **T**ime takes **D**iscussion of **DIGRESS** for "to go off topic")
25. Which of thesis well with fish? (7)

    > **DESPAIR** ( as in: Which of the_si**DES PAIR**s well with fish? )
26. View screen shot extremely closely (7)

    > **SCENERY** ([def] View; **SCREEN** scrambled before closel**Y**)
27. For the first time, a son's two local teams reached the finals (7)

    > **INTENSE** ( as in: For the first time, **IN TEN SE**a-sons two local teams reached the finals )